# creating object of class by dynamically storing [controller class] in variable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

```
UINavigationController *homeNavController;
Class class_ = [YBHomePageViewControlleriPad class];
if(iPhone){
    class_ = [YBHomePageViewControlleriPhone class];
}
class_ *homeController = [[class_ alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(class_) bundle:nil];
homeNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeController];
```

shows - "use of undeclared identifier homeController".

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant assign a className into a string and form objects of that type.

You need to use some advance and difficult way to perform as :

1. Obj-C runtime.
2. "reflection" it enables runtime introspection of classes and objects.
3. IBOutletCollection.

Comment: Are you sure? `UIViewController *homeController = [[class_ alloc] initWithNibName:...]` as indicated in the other answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your classes are both instances of UIViewController just declare homeController as a UIViewController.